# Smallest pandigital number perfect square

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

> What is the smallest $9$-digit number that has all the digits from $1$ to $9$ exactly once and is also a perfect square?

Please give me a method that doesn't involve programming.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The last digit of the number, say $n$, should be in the set $\{1,4,5,6,9\}$, that can work as a starting point.

Comment: Sure, it would be helpful if you could tell me how to proceed from there.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be difficult, it seems not to pan out well.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a 'mathematical method' since the property of being pandigital is base ten dependent.  Using a handheld calculator, I used brute force to find the answer in about 15 or 20 minutes.

Comment: $$11113^2=123498769$$
$$31111^2=967894321$$

Comment: Essam, that was a good attempt. Please keep in mind that the square root of the pandigital number has to be a multiple of 3, hence the sum of digits should be a multiple of three.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439669/smallest-pandigital-number-perfect-square?newreg=04c65ef493b24928b46070226706740a

Answer (score 2):

Just look up [A036744](http://oeis.org/A036744), the penholodigital squares.

The possible solutions are
139854276, 152843769, 157326849, 215384976, 245893761, 254817369,
326597184, 361874529, 375468129, 382945761, 385297641, 412739856,
523814769, 529874361, 537219684, 549386721, 587432169, 589324176,
597362481, 615387249, 627953481, 653927184, 672935481, 697435281,
714653289, 735982641, 743816529, 842973156, 847159236, 923187456

With square roots
11826, 12363, 12543, 14676, 15681, 15963,
18072, 19023, 19377, 19569, 19629, 20316,
22887, 23019, 23178, 23439, 24237, 24276,
24441, 24807, 25059, 25572, 25941, 26409,
26733, 27129, 27273, 29034, 29106, 30384