# A natural number is a perfect square as well as a perfect cube. Show that it is $0$ or $1$ $ ($mod $7$ $)$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A natural number is a perfect square as well as a perfect cube. Show that it is $0$ or $1$ $($mod $7$$)$.

I tried the following.
There are integers numbers $x,y$ such that $n=x^{2}=y^{3}.$ By using Euclidean division, then $x$ and $y$ can be written as $7k,7k+1,7k+2,7k+3,7k+4,7k+5$ or $7k+6$. I am trying some contradictory stuff.

I don't know from where to go from here. Please suggest some hints.

Comment: Also similarly see here(mod 5): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147909/if-an-integer-number-is-a-square-and-a-cube-then-it-can-be-writen-as-5n-5n1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439669/smallest-pandigital-number-perfect-square?newreg=04c65ef493b24928b46070226706740a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that all the squares are equals to $0,1,2$ or $4$ mod $7$ because:

$$0^2=0\pmod 7$$
$$1^2=1\pmod 7$$
$$2^2=4\pmod 7$$
$$3^2=2\pmod 7$$
$$4^2=2\pmod 7$$
$$5^2=4\pmod 7$$
$$6^2=1\pmod 7.$$

And all the cubes are equals to $0,1$ or $6$ mod $7$ because:

$$0^3=0\pmod 7$$
$$1^3=1\pmod 7$$
$$2^3=1\pmod 7$$
$$3^3=6\pmod 7$$
$$4^3=1\pmod 7$$
$$5^3=6\pmod 7$$
$$6^3=6\pmod 7.$$

So if your number is a square and a cube at the same time, then it is necessarily equal to $0$ or $1$ mod $7$.

Comment: I am embarrassed at missing this. Thanks for the simplistic answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, $n$ has to be of the form $$z^{\text{lcm}(2,3)}$$  where $z$ is any integer

If $7|z$, then $z^6\equiv0\pmod7$

Else $7\nmid z\implies(7,z)=1$ using Fermat's little Theorem $z^{7-1}\equiv1$